# Exercise in Hilbert space about invertible operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\;X,Y\;$ be Hilbert Spaces and consider the following linear
>   operators:
>
> - $T_1:D(T_1)\rightarrow Y\;$ as $\;(T_1u)(x)=u'(x)\;$ where $\;D(T_1)=\{u\in C^1[a,b]: u(a)=0\} \;$
> - $T_2:D(T_2)\rightarrow Y\;$ as $\;(T_2u)(x)=u'(x)\;$ where $\;D(T_2)=\{u\in C^1[a,b]: u(b)=0\} \;$
> - $T_3:D(T_3)\rightarrow Y\;$ as $\;(T_3u)(x)=u'(x)\;$ where $\;D(T_3)=\{u\in C^1[a,b]: u(b)=u(a)=0\} \;$
>
> Prove that $\;T_i\;$ is invertible, find $\;Rank(T_i)\;$ and compute
>   $\;{T_i}^{-1}\;$ $\forall 1\le i\le 3\;$

**My attempt:**

It's easy to see that $\;Ker(T_i)=\{0\} \;$ for each case and so $\;T_i\;$ is invertible. In addition, it holds that $\;Rank(T_i)=D({T_i}^{-1})\;$.

At this point I've been stuck! How do I proceed? I believe if I compute $\;{T_i}^{-1}\;$ I 'll be able to answer both questions but I can't come up with any good idea!

Any help would be valuable! Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a remark, should the statement not be $Rank(T_i) = dim(D(T_i^{-1}))$?

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of a linear differential operator is generally an integral operator.  Perhaps you could consider applying the fundamental theorem of calculus to find an expression involving integrals so that when you differentiate the expression, you get your original element of $D(T_i)$ back.